# Implementing Python code in Whitebox GAT?

Tags: python, whitebox-gat

I would like to implement a script that

1. reads base file and appended file;
2. calls the program tool 'Mosaic with feathering';
3. creates a mosaic output file;
4. uses the output file as new base file and so on in a loop.

For starting I'm currently try this python code in Whitebox GAT:

```
import os
try:
   separator = os.sep
   wd = pluginHost.getApplicationDirectory() + separator + "resources" + separator + "samples" + separator + "multimosaic" + separator
   pluginHost.setWorkingDirectory(wd)
   baseFile = wd + "save1.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(basefile)
   appendFile = wd + "save2.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(appendfile)
   outputFile = wd +"output.dep"
   resamplingmethod = "nearest neighbour"
   matchHistograms = "true"
   args = [baseFile, appendFile, outputFile, resamplingmethod, matchHistograms]
   pluginHost.runPlugin("MosaicWithFeathering", args, False)
except Exception, e:
   print e
   pluginHost.showFeedback("Error during script execution.")
finally:
    print "I'm done!"
```

But when I execute the code I don't get any error and no output file is created. 
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code you've posted?

Comment: basically I would like to implement a script that 1. reads base file and appended file;
2. calls the program tool 'Mosaic with feathering';
3. creates a mosaic output file;
4. uses the output file as new base file and so on in a loop.

Comment: Can you edit your post and integrate your comment into the question. Most potential readers won't look at all the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me, calculating slope from the example DEM in the Vermont folder in resources/samples:

```
    import os
    try:
       separator = os.sep
       wd = pluginHost.getApplicationDirectory() + separator + "resources" + separator + "samples" + separator + "Vermont DEM" + separator
       pluginHost.setWorkingDirectory(wd)
       print(wd)
       basefile = wd + 'Vermont DEM.dep'
       pluginHost.returnData(basefile)
       outputFile = wd + "slope.dep"
       zFactor = "1.0"
       args = [basefile, outputFile, zFactor]
       pluginHost.runPlugin("Slope", args, False)
    except Exception, e:
       print e
       pluginHost.showFeedback("Error during script execution.")
    finally:
        print "I'm done!"
```

First off, I noticed you have an error in the naming of your two input files, when you try and load them:

```
   base**F**ile = wd + "save1.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(base**f**ile)
   append**F**ile = wd + "save2.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(append**f**ile)
   outputFile = wd +"output.dep"
```

That will certainly cause an error.
When that was fixed, it seemed to still give me an error, and this is what I found to work for the specific tool you asked about:

```
import os
try:
   separator = os.sep
   wd = pluginHost.getApplicationDirectory() + separator + "resources" + separator + "samples" + separator + "Vermont DEM" + separator
   pluginHost.setWorkingDirectory(wd)
   baseFile = wd + "Vermont DEM.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(baseFile)
   appendFile = wd + "hillshade.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(appendFile)
   outputFile = wd + "output.dep"
   resamplingmethod = "nearest neighbour"
   matchHistograms = "true"
   args = [baseFile, appendFile, outputFile, resamplingmethod, matchHistograms, '4.0']
   pluginHost.runPlugin("MosaicWithFeathering", args, False)
except Exception, e:
   print e
   pluginHost.showFeedback("Error during script execution.")
finally:
    print "I'm done!"
```

With the key difference for me being in this line:

```
   args = [baseFile, appendFile, outputFile, resamplingmethod, matchHistograms, '4.0']
```

Where I added in the *Distance Weight Parameter* argument, which, when you dig into the function's code, it seems to be looking for on lines 225-227.

This caused it to work for me without having to change any of the file names from how you had them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution and it also worked well. Indeed the key difference is in that line, in my original script was missing one argument.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue using

```
inputFile = wd + file
```

instead of base and append file and adding the missing power to the arguments

```
args = [inputFile1, inputFile2, outputFile, resamplingMethod, matchHistograms, power]
```